# Get top 5 sales by store, month and year

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with this sql, for get top 5 sales by store, month and year

```
 SELECT  YEAR(t1.date_at) as year,
          MONTH(t1.date_at) as month,
          (SELECT COUNT(t2.ticket) 
           FROM sac as  t2
           WHERE MONTH(t2.date_at) = MONTH(t1.date_at)
           AND YEAR(t2.date_at) = YEAR(t1.date_at)

           ORDER BY t2.ticket DESC LIMIT 5 ) AS total
 FROM sales as  t1
 WHERE YEAR(t1.date_at) = 2017
 GROUP BY  YEAR(t1.date_at),MONTH(t1.date_at)
```

The result is perfect:

```
2017|1|18977
2017|2|9846
2017|3|270
```

But I need add the store.
I added the store to sql:

```
SELECT  t1.store,YEAR(t1.date_at) as year,
          MONTH(t1.date_at) as month,
          (SELECT COUNT(t2.ticket) 
           FROM sac as  t2
           WHERE MONTH(t2.date_at) = MONTH(t1.date_at)
           AND YEAR(t2.date_at) = YEAR(t1.date_at)
           AND t2.store  = t1.store
           ORDER BY t2.ticket DESC LIMIT 5 ) AS total
 FROM sales as  t1
 WHERE YEAR(t1.date_at) = 2017
 GROUP BY  t1.store, YEAR(t1.date_at),MONTH(t1.date_at)
```

The result is a infinite bucle.

The Ideal result is:

```
YEAR|MONTH|TOTAL|STORE
2017|1|18977|20041
2017|1|17900|345
2017|1|10000|74544
2017|1|8988|2453
2017|1|6942|1056
2017|2|9846|675
2017|2|6487|3421
2017|2|5000|165
2017|2|4785|76
2017|2|699|211
...
...
...
```

Where are the error?

Comment: Can you provide sample data from your tables

Comment: Yes,  
https://pastebin.com/0kHKnUqJ  
id|store|ticket|amount|address|date_at  
1|34|4321|43.50|My house 23|2017-03-10  
2|25|21|11|Drete 15|2017-03-10  
3|64|53|43.98|Olimer 88|2017-03-10

Comment: If you do group by store then all individual store will show result respective to that store. here in your Ideal result you can see that, all the stores are unique. and query rightly showing that result. Please give details of both the tables and expected result to answer effectively

Comment: @Rashedul.Rubel this is the example: https://pastebin.com/Fdc4K60x

Answer (score 0):

*Too long for a comment. May be extended to an answer later.*

Your query does not do, what you think it does.

But first of all, the question is, why do you even read from the sales table, when you apparently have everything in the sac table anyway? This makes everything more complicated than necessary.

So why is your query wrong? The `LIMIT 5` applies to the whole query. All you do with the `LIMIT` clause is counting the tickets with the highest numbers first, which is totally pointless.

The title of your question says, "top 5 sales by store, month and year". To go with your approach, you would have to add a `GROUP BY` in the subquery with your `LIMIT` clause, but that wouldn't work, too, because the subquery (because it's in your SELECT clause) is not allowed to return more than one row.

Again, you say in your title "top 5 sales by store, month and year", but neither your desired result, nor the "ideal result" you have right now reflect that. I don't see anything about "top 5" there. That's why your question is totally confusing.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion by the title, my english is very bad.
The idea is the result is get by motnh and year the 5 top sales por store.

Answer (score 0):

Okay since you can get all from one table so write the query as simple as below(Here I am considering the table name as Ticket) :

```
SELECT t1.store, MONTH(t1.date_at) as m, YEAR(t1.date_at) as y, COUNT(t1.ticket) as total
from Ticket t1 
GROUP BY t1.store,MONTH(t1.date_at),YEAR(t1.date_at)
order by COUNT(t1.ticket) DESC LIMIT 5
```

the above query will fetch your desired result:
The Result:

```
+------+-------+------ +-------+
| store| m     | y     | total |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
| 10   | 04    | 2017  | 2     |
| 11   | 04    | 2017  | 1     |
| 11   | 03    | 2017  | 1     |
+--------+-----+------+--------+
```

Although I don't know what type of DB are you using, hence the query syntax may change based on DB type. But query structure will remain the same.

Comment: The problem is when have many data, the query no filter by months for get the first top sales

Comment: then just remove MONTH(t1.date_at) from both Select and Group by statement based on your condition